# How to make sure same token is passing throughout child requests

Tags: multithreading, jmeter, token

When Load of 50 users is injected, I see some responses are throwing error where it says token is invalid. However, we have kept token valid till 36hrs.

If controller is used for child requests where token will be passed. Script works properly for 10 VUsers but not for 50 VUsers.

Why old thread's token is getting passed to next thread's request?

Answer (score 0):

1. Inspect what token value is being sent out for requests which are failing. You can store token into .jtl results file using [Sample Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/listeners.html#sample_variables) property
2. Inspect **previous** response using [View Results Tree](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener, it might be the case previous request is failing as your system is overloaded or the token cannot be used by multiple concurrent threads or whatever else. If you're running your test in [command-line non-GUI mode](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#non_gui) you can [temporarily configure JMeter to store request and response data](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/useful-jmeter-properties-save-results-save-world) by adding the next lines to *user.properties* file (it's located in JMeter's "bin" folder):

   ```
   jmeter.save.saveservice.output_format=xml
   jmeter.save.saveservice.response_data=true
   jmeter.save.saveservice.samplerData=true
   jmeter.save.saveservice.requestHeaders=true
   jmeter.save.saveservice.url=true
   jmeter.save.saveservice.responseHeaders=true
   ```

   JMeter restart will be required to pick the properties up. When you re-run your test you will be able to inspect results and see request and response details.
3. Check your application logs for any suspicious entries.

Comment: I inspected it and what I noticed is that last 2 threads are sharing same token. Rest all threads had independent tokens. It's difficult for me to conclude why it's happened but yes I saw my systems memory was 86 percent occupied.